# C - Argparse (Argument struct)

Tags: c, parsing, console

I'm trying to make something like Python's `argparse` in C.

I created this `Argument` struct and functions; is my code good so far?

### Argument.h:

```
#ifndef ARGUMENT_H
#define ARGUMENT_H

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct Argument{
    char **names;
    char *action;
    char *metavar;
    char *nargs;
    char *type;
    char **choices;
    char *defaultValue;
    bool required;
    char *help;
};
struct Argument Argument_new(char**,char*,char*,char*,char*,char**,char*,bool*,char*);

#endif
```

### Argument.c:

```
#include "argument.h"

const char *Argument_ACTIONS[]={
    "default",
    "store_true",
    "store_false",
    "show_help",
    "show_version",
    NULL
};
const char *Argument_NARGS_PATTERNS[]={
    "([1-9]\\d*)?\\+",
    "[1-9]\\d*",
    "[1-9]\\d*-[1-9]\\d*"
};
struct Argument Argument_new(char **names,char *action,char *metavar,char *nargs,char *type,char **choices,char *defaultValue,bool *required,char *help){
    struct Argument self;
    size_t namesCount=0;
    char **namesStart=names;
    while(*names++){
        namesCount++;
    }
    int i;
    self.names=malloc(namesCount*sizeof(*names));
    for(i=0,names=namesStart;*names;names++,i++){
        if(false/*not match(*names,"^-{1,2}(?!-)")*/){
            //error
        }else{
            self.names[i]=malloc(strlen(*names)+1);
            strcpy(self.names[i],*names);
        }
    }
    if(action==NULL){
        self.action=malloc(strlen(Argument_ACTIONS[0])+1);
        strcpy(self.action,Argument_ACTIONS[0]);
    }else{
        bool good=false;
        const char **ptr=Argument_ACTIONS;
        while(*ptr){
            if(strcmp(action,*ptr)==0){
                good=true;
                break;
            }
            ptr++;
        }
        if(!good){
            //error
        }else{
            self.action=malloc(strlen(action)+1);
            strcpy(self.action,action);
        }
    }
    if(metavar==NULL){
        self.metavar=malloc(strlen(self.names[namesCount-1])+1);
        strcpy(self.metavar,self.names[namesCount-1]);
        char *ptr=self.metavar;
        while(*ptr){
            *ptr=(char)toupper(*ptr);
            ptr++;
        }
    }else{
        self.metavar=malloc(strlen(metavar)+1);
        strcpy(self.metavar,metavar);
    }
    if(nargs==NULL){
        self.nargs=malloc(strlen("1")+1);
        strcpy(self.nargs,"1");
    }else{
        if(false/*not match(*nargs,???)*/){
            //error
        }else{
            self.nargs=malloc(strlen(nargs)+1);
            strcpy(self.nargs,nargs);
        }
    }
    if(type==NULL){
        self.type=malloc(strlen("string")+1);
        strcpy(self.type,"string");
    }else{
        if(false/*not match(*type,"^(string|((\+|-)?int((>|<|>=|<=|!=)-?[1-9]\d+)?))$")*/){
            //error
        }else{
            self.type=malloc(strlen(type)+1);
            strcpy(self.type,type);
        }
    }
    if(choices==NULL){
        self.choices=malloc(sizeof(NULL));
        self.choices=NULL;
    }else{
        size_t choicesCount=0;
        char **choicesStart=choices;
        while(*choices++){
            choicesCount++;
        }
        self.choices=malloc(choicesCount*sizeof(*choices));
        for(i=0,choices=choicesStart;*choices;choices++,i++){
            self.choices[i]=malloc(strlen(*choices)+1);
            strcpy(self.choices[i],*choices);
        }
    }
    if(defaultValue==NULL){
        if(self.choices==NULL){
            self.defaultValue=malloc(sizeof(NULL));
            self.defaultValue=NULL;
        }else{
            self.defaultValue=malloc(strlen(self.choices[0])+1);
            strcpy(self.defaultValue,self.choices[0]);
        }
    }else{
        self.defaultValue=malloc(strlen(defaultValue)+1);
        strcpy(self.defaultValue,defaultValue);
    }
    self.required=malloc(sizeof(bool));
    if(self.action==Argument_ACTIONS[0]){
        if(self.defaultValue!=NULL){
            self.required=false;
        }else if(required!=NULL){
            self.required=required;
        }else{
            self.required=true;
        }
    }else{
        self.required=false;
    }
    if(help==NULL){
        self.help=malloc(sizeof("")+1);
        strcpy(self.help,"");
    }else{
        self.help=malloc(sizeof(strlen(help))+1);
        strcpy(self.help,help);
    }
    return self;
}
```

I want to know what can be done better and "cleaner".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Includes

The interface needs only `<stdbool.h>` - the rest of the standard headers only need to be included in the implementation file.

## Interface

The declaration isn't very helpful:

```
struct Argument Argument_new(char**,char*,char*,char*,char*,char**,char*,bool*,char*);
```

What does each argument mean?  What are the valid ranges of each argument?  This is where users will look for documentation, but they find nothing.

## Memory allocation

Match the allocation to the type we're assigning *to*, so we don't have to go back and check whether the types match:

```
self.names = malloc(namesCount * sizeof *self.names);
```

And we *must* test whether we got a valid pointer back from `malloc()`!

## Dead code

This block looks incomplete; should it be finished, or removed?

```
    if(false/*not match(*names,"^-{1,2}(?!-)")*/){
        //error
```

## `sizeof` or `strlen()`

This probably isn't what you meant:

```
    self.help=malloc(sizeof(strlen(help))+1);
```

`sizeof strlen(help)` is `sizeof (size_t)`.  You probably meant simply

```
    self.help = malloc(strlen(help)+1);
```

## Don't forget to clean up

At the same time as you write a "constructor" that does lots of `malloc()`, you should be writing the corresponding clean-up function, that knows how to `free()` all these allocations.

Comment: Thanks for review.
I changed the declaration to: `struct Argument Argument_new(char **names,char *action,char *metavar,char *nargs,char *type,char **choices,char *defaultValue,bool *required,char *help);` so its more helpful and clean than it was.
Is there any difference between `sizeof *names` and `sizeof(*names)`?
"This block looks incomplete; should it be finished, or removed?".
I have little problem with regex on windows so I will finish that blocks of code.
"This probably isn't what you meant".
You are right, I didn't notice that, thanks again.

Comment: `sizeof (*names)` is just the same as `sizeof *names` (the parentheses are just ordinary expression parentheses, but sometimes people think that `sizeof` needs them; sometimes you also see redundant parens with `return`.  I think they look ugly when they are not needed!

Comment: Minor nitpicking: unless I am mistaken, sizeof strlen(help) is sizeof(size_t).

Comment: Thanks Martin - fixed  (I must be showing my age there!)